# Converting one publisher into another publisher in Combine

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I am new to combine and i am trying write the network layer for my App.

My network call is

```
protocol NetworkRequest {
    associatedtype model
    func decode(_ data:Data) -> AnyPublisher<model,Error>
}

extension NetworkRequest {

 fileprivate func load<model>(_ url:URL, session:NetworkSession = URLSession.shared) -> AnyPublisher<model,Error> {
    
    return session.loadData(for: URLRequest(url: url))
        .mapError { error in
            .network(description: error.localizedDescription)
        }
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { pair in
            self.decode(pair.data)
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
 }

}
```

my decode method is

```
func decode(_ data:Data) -> AnyPublisher<model,Error>
```

and my session.loadData is

```
func loadData(for URLRequest: URLRequest) -> AnyPublisher<(data: Data, response: URLResponse), URLError>
```

The problem is i am getting an error `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

I am not exactly sure what i am doing wrong here. I simply want to use the decode method to get a publisher.

Comment: You're not giving enough information. When I supply enough information by just making up the missing stuff, your code compiles fine! Please show enough real code to allow me to try to compile it and get exactly the error you're getting.

Comment: @matt Please see my new edit.

Comment: Why do you need a decode func when Combine has a decode operator?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because the intention is to build a Generic NetworkRequest that is usable with other forms of Data e.g to build UIImage and not only to decode JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have a type mismatch here. `publisher` is of type `AnyPublisher` whereas the type that you're assigning to it is a `FlatMap`. That happens normally, when using operators, and the solution is to type-erase with `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` operator:

```
var publisher : AnyPublisher<Model, Error> = 
    session.loadData(for: URLRequest(url: url))
           .flatMap { (data,response) -> AnyPublisher<Model,Error> in
               self.decode(data)
           }
           .eraseToAnyPublisher() // add this
```

<sub>Btw, you should use CapitalCase for types, e.g. `Model`</sub>

---

**Update**: based on your question changes

It's again a type mismatch, but in this case, with a `Model` type. When you declare your `load` function like this:

```
func load<Model>(_ url: URL, ...) -> AnyPublisher<Model,Error> {
```

the generic type `Model` of the function is not the same as the associated type `Model` - they are completely different types, which just have the same name. So, `decode` returns `Self.Model`, but `load` wants to return its own `Model`, so there's a mismatch.

The solution is simply to remove the function's `Model` from the signature:

```
func load(_ url: URL, ...) -> AnyPublisher<Model, Error>
```

---

Combine makes a heavy use of type inference which simplifies things a great deal when it works, or gives cryptic and misplaced errors when it doesn't. To diagnose errors like this with Combine, use explicit types. For example, inside `flatMap` explicitly specify what type you're returning:

```
.flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1)) { pair -> AnyPublisher<Model, Error> in
     self.decode(pair.data)
}
```

the above would've complained about a mismatch of `Self.Model` and `Model`.

Comment: Yes i already did that on adding .eraseToAnyPublisher() i get "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: See my Edit to the question

Comment: Why is there a mismatch actually ? Both `load` and `decode` are part of the `NetworkRequest` protocol so when a class implements  `NetworkRequest` shouldn't the generic type `model` be  the same for both methods ?

Comment: @dev_ios999 Because - at least in the code in question - `load` defines its own additional (though having the same name) generic type in its function signature. So, remove that.

Comment: Hmm ok but then how can i define `load` in a way that it references the same generic type `model` as described in `NetworkRequest` instead of defining its own additional type.

Comment: @dev_ios999, didn't I address that? I showed in my updated answer how to define `load`. Remove `model` from the function signature and just like `decode` it would use the associated type `model` (and please CapitalCase your types - that's the adopted convention)